# Python - issue with permissions in copy files script

Tags: python

I need to prepare script which user backups in Python (I'm the beginner in Python) and I have a problem with copy files beetwen catalogs. When I run script, I get this error:

```
*PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/User/Documents/PythonProjects\\New catalog'*
```

New catalog is a dir which is in PythonProjects dir.

What I did:

I checked permissions in catalog PythonProjects (User has persmissions to read/save/modify this catalog). I dont' know what I can to do next step to verify this issue. I saw many threads and any solution doesn't fix my issue.

This is my code:

```py
import shutil
import os
sourceCatalog = "C:/Users/User/Documents/PythonProjects"
destinationCatalog = "D:/BACKUP_NEW"

files = os.listdir(sourceCatalog)

for filesNames in files:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(sourceCatalog, filesNames), destinationCatalog)
```

Thank you for potential tips.

Comment: Do you have a *D:/BACKUP\_NEW* directory?

Comment: @Friedrich indeed, I noticed it a while seconds ago.

Comment: @CristiFati yes, I have it in a second partition (I have one physical disk SSD).

Comment: @Friedrich oh, sorry. Thank you for that.
I should use shutil.copytree, when I have in my source catalog files and dirs? Is matter what command I should to use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module offers several functions to copy files or directories. As opposed to the `cp` or `copy` commands, `shutil.copy[2]` however, is not a one size fits all solution.

Namely, `shutil.copy2` will refuse to copy a directory and give the "permission denied" error (at least on Windows). To copy a directory - or rather an entire directory tree - `shutil.copytree` is the right command.

So the fixed code reads:

```py
import shutil
import os
sourceCatalog = "C:/Users/User/Documents/PythonProjects"
destinationCatalog = "D:/BACKUP_NEW"

files = os.listdir(sourceCatalog)

for filesNames in files:
    shutil.copytree(os.path.join(sourceCatalog, filesNames), destinationCatalog)
```